# Bad data received from Arduino serial while reading from analog port

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, analog-digital-converter, node-serialport

Maybe this is just a nonsense, but it's driving me crazy. I'm trying to read one analog port in Arduino and send the value through the serial port to JavaScript using node. When I show the data in the Arduino console, everything works fine, but when I use the terminal in Mac, some values appear splited in two lines.

```
460
460
4
60
460
```

The code I'm using is:

Arduino:

```
const int analogInPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(500000);
}

void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  delay(200);
}
```

Node:

```
var com = require('serialport').SerialPort;

var opts = {baudrate: 500000};

var serialPort = new com('/dev/tty.usbmodem641', opts);

serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

The code couldn't be simpler, but still doesn't work properly. I know I'm missing something but I can't see it. I have tested different baudrates, but nothings works. Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `500000` looks like an unusual baud rate value, and would be expected to be more susceptible to noise.  Have you tried a more "standard" baud rate like `115200`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with other baudrates and still the same. When I try to read a number, for example 525 from the ADC, sometimes it split in 5 and 25 when reading by the computer through serial port. It also happens with, for example 1021 (1 - 021, 10 - 21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe [Elias Benevedes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730405/elias-benevedes) is trying to suggest this in their answer: right now your Arduino data is not delimited at all. Suppose your `sensorValue` always reads as `1`. In this case the output from Arduino will be

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111....
```

And so on; because you print the integer value without any delimiters. The way it is parsed into different numbers, therefore, has to do with the timing of the arrival of the data. Continuing with the example above then, sometimes your value is read as `1`, sometimes as `11`, sometimes as `111` and so on, just depending on the timing of the reads and the writes.

The way to begin to fix it is to insert some non-numeric data between your sensor reading outpus.  One (again, this is perhaps what [Elias Benevedes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730405/elias-benevedes) has in mind) is to insert line breaks between every number printed

```
 Serial.println(sensorValue);
```

Another way would be to add spaces between the data

```
 Serial.print(sensorValue);
 Serial.print(" ");
```

Either solution would separate your numeric readings from each other, which is what you want.

Comment: I'm trying right now.Using the delimiter instead of trusting in reading timing from the computer.

Comment: Well, it works!!
I love JavaScript :)
I have use `Serial.println()` in Arduino's code and I have use a parser in JavaScript's code when opening the serial port: `var serialPort = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.usbmodem641', {baudrate: 115200, parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")});`. I have lowered a little the baudrate, but it works perfectly for everyone. I have even read data from the ADC at 2kHz (500us) :)

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

I had this happen to me once also. Serial.print() sends data to the arduino. Serial.println() will send information from the arduino to the computer Serial message board (or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Mmmm.. the only difference between `Serial.print()` and Serial.println()` is the line termination that's added to the end.

Comment: Last time I tried that fix, it worked. Sorry if I gave bad information. BTW, this Q should be moved to electronics...

Comment: Move to electronics: maybe? There is a number of Arduino questions here. The direction of `Serial.print()` and `Serial.println()` is the same: it outputs data on Arduino's serial port.  Maybe you were trying to suggest that the OP use `Serial.println()` for everything?

Comment: Arduino is working correctly. This question is not related with Arduino directly. The problem is on the computer side, because when I read the data stream, I trust on timing instead delimiting the data I send from the Arduino (as angelatlarge has indicated above). The difference between print and println is the output stream I thought: `print() -> 121212121212`  `println() -> 12\n12\n12\n12\n12\n12\n`.